# "Async" function issue in Azure DevOps Custom Extension Development

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

I am new for Azure Custom DevOps extension. I have developed and extension and trying to use the same in Azure DevOps pipline. But facing issue as below.

**"SyntaxError: Unexpected token function"**

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P72o5.png)

Checked for fix in the internet, many have suggested as the version of Node.js would be the issue. Hence I have added "Node.js tool installer" step also in the pipeline. But still the error is same.

Followed below links for the DevOps Custom Extension Development.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/with-azure-sdk/stop-start-virtual-machine

Note: I am able to run the Node.js application locally and getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing Node executor of task is using very old node version.

To fix it specify in your task.json Node16 in execution section. For example:

```
"execution": {
  "Node16": {
    "target": "index.js"
  }
}
```